# 2D ListPlot with separate color function

Tags: plotting, color

Suppose a data array of the form `{{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2}...}`, is it possible to use `ListPlot` where x,y specify the point position and z (Hue[z]) specify the color of each point?

Comment: yes, use the `ColorFunction` see ref/ListPlot3D under Color by scaled x, y, and z values. there is example there to do this.

Comment: @Nasser Yes, I know that can be done with 3D list plots, but I want a 2D plot where z is only used for coloring

Comment: So you only want to plot the {x,y} part of the list? and use the z component for coloring of the point? I miss-understood.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really must use `ListPlot` and not `Graphics` as Ubpdqn showed, then here is a hack.

The problem is that `ColorFunction` for 2D takes only `{x,y}`. One way is to get the z value yourself from the data. But for this you need the current index.

So simply make an index, set it to zero, and increment it each time the `ColorFunction` is called. Like this. Notice, must use `Joined -> True` for this to work.

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {40, 3}];
n = 0; (*make sure to set this to zero before each call*)
ListPlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]],PlotStyle->Directive[PointSize[Large]],Joined -> True,
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[data[[++n, 3]]] ]] /. Line[a__] :> Point[a]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

reference [2D ListPlot with separate color function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39726/2d-listplot-with-separate-color-function)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. How could I use a certain color map like `"TemperatureMap` or my own color table: `number = Length@data[[All,3]]; colTable = {Table[{Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, x]}, {x, 1/number, 1, 
    1/number}]}; colTable = Flatten[colTable];`

Answer (score 11):

You could achieve this using `Graphics`, for example:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 3}];
Graphics[{Hue[#3], PointSize[0.02], Point[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ data, 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]