# Projection of 3d data to 2d with ListPlot and color function

Tags: plotting, color

This question is related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39726/2d-listplot-with-separate-color-function) one or [that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157963/listplot-point-colors-by-list-of-colorfunctions).

```
SeedRandom[1];

data = RandomInteger[100, {100, 3}];

x = data[[All,1]];
y = data[[All,2]];
z = data[[All,3]];
```

I want to use `ListPlot` to show x versus y as points whereby the color should represent z.

How can I use a certain color map like `TemperatureMap` or my own color table?

```
(* e.g. own color table *)
number = Length@z; 
colTable = {Table[{Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, i]}, {i, 1/number, 1, 1/number}]}; 
colTable = Flatten[colTable];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blatantly stealing three-quarters of @ubpdqn's answer (particularly the rescaled `ColorFunction`), you can use `Style` to get it working in `ListPlot`, as requested by the OP:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomInteger[100, {100, 3}];

cf = ColorData["TemperatureMap", Rescale[#, MinMax[data[[All, 3]]]]] &;
Row[{ListPlot[Style[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, cf[#[[3]]]] & /@ data, 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], ImageSize -> 350], 
  BarLegend[{cf[#] &, {0, 100}}, Range[0, 100, 10]]}]
```

[image]

And, of course, you can change out `"TemperatureMap"` for any other colour scheme.

Answer (score 2):

In such cases, I go with `Graphics`.

```
data = RandomInteger[100, {100, 3}];

{z1, z2} = MinMax[data[[All,3]]];
Grid[
{{Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Hue[(#[[3]] - z1)/(z2 - z1)/2 + 0.5], 
   Point[#[[1 ;; 2]]]} & /@ data, Frame -> True],
  BarLegend[{Hue, {z1, z2}}]}}]
```

[image]

With your custom colormap

```
clfun[x_] := Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, x]
{z1, z2} = MinMax[data[[All,3]]];
Grid[
{{Graphics[{PointSize[Large], clfun[(#[[3]] - z1)/(z2 - z1)/2 + 0.5],
    Point[#[[1 ;; 2]]]} & /@ data, Frame -> True],
 BarLegend[{clfun[#] &, {0, 1}}, Ticks -> {{0, z1}, {1, z2}}]}}]
```

[image]

To use a `TemperatureMap`

```
clfun[x_] := ColorData["TemperatureMap"][x]
```

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot ... how can I to use `ListPlot` because there I can add `PlotRange` and other keywords which Graphics does not have. For the solution of the custom colormap I get the info: "Ticks is not an option of BarLegend". Is it possible to access the colors of `TemperatureMap`?

Comment: You can use `PlotRage` with `Graphics`. `Ticks` appears in red with `BarLegend` but it works. Which version you are using. There might be some problem with old versions.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions with the color map. I am using 11.2 -> `PlotRange` is possible. I thought that `ListPlot` is usally used to plot data intead of  using `Graphics`?

Comment: well, deep inside `ListPlot` is a `Graphics` ;). You are right, it is more convenient to use `ListPlot` or `ListLinePlot`  while plotting data due to its inbuilt options. You can do the same thing using `Graphics` but it takes more efforts and commands.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use "TemperatureMap" is in-built color scheme,e.g.:

```
cf = ColorData["TemperatureMap", Rescale[#, MinMax[data[[All, 3]]]]] &;
Row[{Graphics[{cf@#3, PointSize[0.04], 
      Tooltip[Point[{#1, #2}], #3]} & @@@ data, Frame -> True, 
   ImageSize -> 200],
  BarLegend[{cf[#] &, {0, 100}}, Range[0, 100, 10]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: You can use that `ColorFunction` in `ListPlot`, too, as the OP seems to want: `ListPlot[Style[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, ColorData["TemperatureMap", Rescale[#[[3]], MinMax[data[[All, 3]]]]]] & /@ data, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]`.

Comment: @aardvark2012 very good point...put it is an answer as it uses ListPlot :)

Comment: @aardvark2012: yes please ... I would like to see also the solutions with `ListPlot`.